Why does an exception thrown in a drop-event in WPF is not catched in App .DispatcherUnhandledException?
I created a new WPF Application (.net Framework).
App.xaml looks like this:
<Application x:Class="TestD_D_Exception.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestD_D_Exception"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

and this is the handler in App.xaml.cs
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Application_DispatcherUnhandledException");
}

In my MainWindow there is only one control:
<TextBlock Name="dropZone"
           Text="Drop something here"
           AllowDrop="True" 
           DragDrop.Drop="dropZone_Drop"/> 

And the event handler looks like this:
private void dropZone_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

When I drop a EMail from outlook into the TextBlock Outlook opens a MessageBox which looks like this:

When I change the NotImplementedException to a simple generic Exception, nothing happens.
Why is the exception not handled by DispatcherUnhandledException? Why it seems to be handled by outlook? How to handle exceptions which are thrown in a drop-handler? In there a way to handle these exception globally?

That's a special case because OLE is involved. See the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969983/exception-swallowed-when-doing-drag-and-drop

The problem seems to be releated to the nature of OLE (which is the technology behind Drag&Drop). The details are described here (WinForms has the same problem):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567507/9930052
So there seems to be no way to create a global exception handler for these. So I chose to handle exceptions like this:
private void dropZone_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {
        //Do drag&drop things here
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        m_log.Log(exception.Message);
    }
}

Another problem is that Outlook is frozen as long as the event-function is not left. This means if you open a modal error-MessageBox in the catch-handler outlook is frozen until the user closes the MessageBox.
